# Issue with .prop("checked", true)?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
116   $.each(data.entries, function(id, item) {
117       console.log($("input[type=checkbox][value=" + item + "]").is(":checked"));
118       $("input[type=checkbox][value=" + item + "]").prop("checked", true);
119       console.log($("input[type=checkbox][value=" + item + "]").is(":checked"));
120   })
```

For the life of me I can't get my checkbox to check:

```
swot-nav.js:117 false
swot-nav.js:119 false
```

This doesn't work either:

```
116    $.each(data.entries, function(id, item) {
117        console.log($(":checkbox[value=" + item + "]").is(":checked"));
118        $(":checkbox[value=" + item + "]").prop("checked", "true");
119        console.log($(":checkbox[value=" + item + "]").is(":checked"));
120    })
```

(same result)

What could I be missing?

**Edit:**

This is taking place in the success function of an Ajax Call.

This is what the data looks like:

`data = {'label': 'D1- DC Test 1', 'details': '', 'type': 'D', 'entries': [20, 21, 22]`

Here's a fiddle where it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/e3arwp7q/

There must be something wrong deeper in my code. If this looks to everyone like it is supposed to work, then maybe I should look elsewhere.

Comment: 1st: you need to `console.log(item)` and see if it gets the correct values .. and let's know what is the output of `item` and Is there any input with this value or not??

Comment: I did that and the values are matching the values in the inspector. Will this not work in the event that multiple checkboxes have the same value?

Comment: A colon. `.is()` expects a selector and the [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) requires a colon as a prefix operator. Currently, `.is('checked')` is determining whether the `<input>` is a `<checked>` element.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable**  [mcve] that includes applicable data sample and html

Comment: @JonathanLonowski still reporting false with the colon :/

Comment: @AdamStarrh Can you include a sample of the markup and `data.entries`? Have you checked that the selector is always finding an `<input>`? – https://jsfiddle.net/gctL8jh1/.

Comment: Can an input selector find something other than an input?  I didn't even know that was an option, thought I would get an error, not something totally different. It seems like it might be though... It seems like I'm getting something called a `prevObj`.

Comment: Hang on, it looks like this code is set up to generate the checkboxes in an earlier method.... I bet that is part of the problem! These boxes are appearing after the document loads! Thanks for the tip. I guess I just assumed if I didn't get an error I was getting what I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think you need to loop through your `checkbox`s .. the next code will loop through just the `unchecked` inputs

```
$.each(data.entries, function(id, item) {
   $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(){
      $(this).filter('[value=' + item + ']').prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

> Note: The above code will work if 1- output of `item` matching the
>   value of `checkbox` 2- if you have more than one `checkbox` with the
>   same value

The next code will work for all `checkbox` inputs

```
$.each(data.entries, function(id, item) {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
      var checked_or_not = this.checked;
      console.log(checked_or_not);
      if(checked_or_not === false){
        $(this).filter('[value=' + item + ']').prop("checked", true);
      }
      console.log(checked_or_not);
   });
});
```

Comment: Still getting two Falses! There must be something else going on here.

Comment: @AdamStarrh what the `false` you got with my code?? I didn't output anything from it .. I just checked the unchecked input with value you want

Comment: `console.log($(":checkbox[value=" + item + "]").is(":checked"))` reports false before and after I plug this in (just like in my example). I'm not sure why that would be. I can get it to work in JSFiddle, so there must be a problem elsewhere in my interface. Something interfering maybe

Comment: @AdamStarrh *I can get it to work in JSFiddle* ?? ok keep eyes on console for errors .. may be you forgot to include jquery in your website

Comment: No, it's definitely included. This UI makes extensive use of jQuery. Absolutely zero errors in the console, which is why this is so frustrating.

Comment: Okay, I tried the code for ALL checkboxes. About 75-80% of them said `True` others said `False`.

Comment: Don't feel obligated to keep troubleshooting. I was just checking to see if I missed something obvious. I will have to figure out what this issue is.

Comment: @AdamStarrh may be the `item` values returns with some whitespaces so you can `trim()` it or you can try `[value*=' + item + ']` add `*` after `value`

Comment: Still no luck, but I think I might have found the problem. The boxes are being generated after the page is loaded.

Comment: @AdamStarrh you mean generated by ajax??

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is that you are passing the wrong argument to the `is` method. Use `.is(':checked')` instead.

Comment: It's still reporting false, even with the colon

Comment: kindly explain what you are trying to achieve because your original question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to check if a checkbox is checked? or are you trying to check (tick) the checkboxes?

Comment: Yeah, just trying to tick the box. The console output was just to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **:checked** selector.

add colon before checked

change **is("checked")** to **is(":checked")**